# Loading resource on background thread in non-async context

Tags: c#, asynchronous, background-process

I'm working with an external library that expects me to produce bitmaps when it calls `GetImage` for the following interface it exposes:

```
public interface IImageProvider
{
    Bitmap GetImage(string imageId);
}
```

The library asks for them in bulk - i.e. it calls `GetImage()` repeatedly on the UI thread, thus creating substantial UI lag. Now, I have time to pre-render images for each of these ids before the library actually asks for them. I would like to do so on a background thread, but I am obviously not in a position to return a `Task<Bitmap>` back through the interface.

What I'm essentially trying to achieve is summmarized below: Let's say I create a library - `MySvgLibrary`:

```
public interface MySvgLibrary
{
    void Preload();
    Dictionary<string, Bitmap> Library { get; }
}
```

I now want to `Task.Run(() => _myLibrary.Preload() }`. Given that I don't think I can use async/await here (since I cannot return a `Task<Bitmap>`, I don't see how I can use, say, a `TaskCompletionSource` in this context. How do I know that `Preload` is finished? I mean, I could check if `Library` is `null` and spin until it isn't (and that does work, btw) but that approach makes me nauseous. Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have to preload all the images at once, or is it a continuous process?

Comment: You can interrogate the `Task` returned from `Task.Run()` to see if it has finished, using `Task.Wait(0)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I can spread it out if I like.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Tempting suggestion, I hadn't thought of that :)

Comment: How about using a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) instead of a normal `Dictionary`? You could have a background process adding rendered images to the dictionary, and on the UI thread just grab the images using the `TryGetValue` method. This class is thread-safe, so no synchronization is needed.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, I really like that option. I'm probably going with that - although the `Wait(0)` trick is really neat!

Comment: You'll probably need both approaches. When the UI needs an image and you look at the dictionary, there can be 3 scenarios: 1) It's in the dictionary fully loaded, 2) It's in the dictionary loading, 3) it's not in the dictionary. With the concurrent dictionary you can safely add items from one thread and read them from another. But you still need to handle items that are half loaded. I would put it the dictionary the Tasks, or a custom object with the knowledge of the loading status, as soon as you start loading them, otherwise you could load the same image multiple times.

Comment: @FrancescCastells I thought about that. As I understand it, `ConcurrentDictionary` is entirely trustworthy in that it's state is binary - a KeyValue tuple is either fully there or it is not. If my `TryGetValue` returns false, I jump into a path where I render the image (I need it now), `TryAdd` it to the dictionary, and return it. If I, every now and then, render an image twice (extremely unlikely), then that's OK. Don't you think that should work?

Comment: @AlexanderHøst My proposal was to avoid the situation where you start preloading 10 images and before they are completed your UI requests them. In your scenario, the UI won't find them in the dictionary so they'll be loaded from scratch. In my proposal, the UI will use the ones that are already being preloaded, so you'll avoid loading them twice and there'll be a lot less wait for the user. But if this scenario is not going to happen often, you can of course simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the `MySvgLibrary` class. It uses a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) for storing the bitmaps, and a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) for controlling the degree of parallelism (how many threads are allowed to create images in parallel).

```
public class MySvgLibrary
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<Bitmap>> _dictionary;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public MySvgLibrary(int degreeOfParallelism = 1)
    {
        _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<Bitmap>>();
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(degreeOfParallelism);
    }

    public Task<Bitmap> GetImageAsync(string key)
    {
        return _dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, _ => Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            try
            {
                return CreateImage(key);
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }));
    }

    public Bitmap GetImage(string key)
    {
        return GetImageAsync(key).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public void PreloadImage(string key)
    {
        var fireAndForget = GetImageAsync(key);
    }

    private Bitmap CreateImage(string key)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulate some heavy computation
        return new Bitmap(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var svgLibrary = new MySvgLibrary(degreeOfParallelism: 2);
svgLibrary.PreloadImage("SomeKey"); // the preloading happens in background threads
Bitmap bitmap = svgLibrary.GetImage("SomeKey"); // blocks if the bitmap is not ready yet
```

You should put the actual code that produces the images into the `CreateImage` method. In case an exception is thrown by the `CreateImage`, the exception will be propagated and rethrown when the `GetImage` is called.

Comment: Really nice - I was headed in a similar direction, although without the `SemaphorSlim`. Question though - is there much overhead in `Task.Run`ning each `Preload()` individually? It there a reason why you did it that way and not all of them in bulk inside a `Task.Run`? It's not important to me to split up the work as long as it runs in the background.

Comment: @AlexanderHøst the overhead of `Task.Run` is very small, and should be totally dwarfed by the work of creating the bitmap. To get an idea how minuscule it is, if hypothetically you had no work to do, then the pure overhead would limit your throughput to around 1,000,000 tasks per second (in a mediocre PC).

Comment: That's a nice solution. I would propose two improvements: 1. GetImage should return the Task instead of awaiting it synchronously. Then the consumer of this method can decide how to handle the wait. 2. As the class itself doesn't have anything specific to loading bitmaps, it can be abstracted so that it can be used to do any sort of background work based on a key. The actual work could be done in a subclass, injecting a function, etc.

Comment: @FrancescCastells nice suggestions about abstracting the class. About the `GetImage` method, there is already a public method `GetImageAsync`. I added the blocking `GetImage` for convenience because the external library seems to be non-async-friendly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well that clears up some things for me. I feel I have read somewhere (probably Stephen Cleary's blog on async) that `await`s inside `Task.Run`s carries some overhead (getting the thread-pool thread, context switch after `await` and returning the thread pool thread). Might have been for ASP.NET so not sure if it applies fully to this case.

Comment: According to Stephen Cleary `Task.Run` in `ASP.NET` is problematic becauses it messes up the heuristics of the `ASP.NET` engine, since it uses the same `ThreadPool` for serving web requests. It is also bad for spawning [fire-and-forget](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) tasks because the engine doesn't know about them and may kill them at any moment by recycling the application. But for desktop apps `Task.Run` is OK. If you fire too many of them you could cause `ThreadPool` starvation though. This is why I included the `SemaphoreSlim` in the solution.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That makes sense. Is there something special about 2 threads allowed by the semaphor at a time, or is just some number you think will avoid `ThreadPool` starvation?

Comment: No, It's just an example, nothing special. Generally you don't want to have more CPU-bound tasks running concurrently, than the available processors/cores of the local machine (`Environment.ProcessorCount`). If preloading bitmaps is a low priority job, and you are doing other important heavy computations at the same time, or the external library does, you could configure the `MySvgLibrary` with `degreeOfParallelism: 1` to reduce to a single core the max CPU resources it consumes.

Comment: Btw a `ThreadPool` starvation is just a temporary problem, because the `ThreadPool` when starved injects new threads at a rate of one every 500 msec, so eventually there will be enough threads to serve all tasks. But this scenario could cause awkward temporary hiccups. For example a `System.Timers.Timer` could stop firing regularly for a while, because it's `Elapsed` event is running in `ThreadPool` threads. If you are anticipating such a scenario you can preemptively increase the pool of threads by calling the `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` method during the app initialization.